# How to Deploy Strapi and React at one hosting?

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, devops, strapi

everyone.
I just deployed Strapi and React project.
But I hosted individual, so that seems to be very strange.
How to I do deploy at one hosting. I can't find any guides about that.

Like this:

Strapi:
 https://nuclear-leagcy.herokuapp.com/admin 
 https://nuclear-leagcy.herokuapp.com/graphql

React
 https://nuclear-leagcy.herokuapp.com

I think I have to define server.js with express. But I don't have any ideas about that now.

Additions.
I want to use graphql in production, but want to disable playground interface in production so others can't to do it.

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 3.0.0.beta.19.5 to deploy Strapi + React in the same server you need to do the following things.

**rootDir** = means the root folder of the Strapi project.

You need to create a new Middleware, rootDir/middlewares/serve-react, and this 2 files in there.

1. defaults.json

```
{
  "serve-react": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

2. index.js

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies
 */

// Node.js core.
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const koaStatic = require('koa-static');

/**
 * Serve react hook
 */

module.exports = strapi => {

  return {
    /**
     * Initialize the hook
     */

    async initialize() {
      const {maxAge, path: publicPath} = strapi.config.middleware.settings.public;
      const staticDir = path.resolve(strapi.dir, publicPath || strapi.config.paths.static);

      strapi.router.get(
        '/*',
        async (ctx, next) => {
          const parse = path.parse(ctx.url);
          ctx.url = path.join(parse.dir, parse.base);

          await next();
        },
        koaStatic(staticDir, {
          maxage: maxAge,
          defer: false, // do not allow other middleware to serve content before this one
        })
      );

      // if no resource is matched by koa-static, just default to serve index file
      // useful for SPA routes
      strapi.router.get('*', ctx => {
        ctx.type = 'html';
        ctx.body = fs.createReadStream(path.join(staticDir + '/index.html'));
      });
    },
  };
};
```

Add the middleware just created in the chain. rootDir/config/middleware.json. Notice the "serve-react" at the end of the "after" property, is the only thing added in this case.

```
{
  "timeout": 100,
  "load": {
    "before": [
      "responseTime",
      "logger",
      "cors",
      "responses",
      "gzip"
    ],
    "order": [
      "Define the middlewares' load order by putting their name in this array is the right order"
    ],
    "after": [
      "parser",
      "router",
      "serve-react"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this an answer for deploy React and Strapi proejct at one url hosting?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain how to make folder structure of react and strapi for following your guide? Where should I put react project?

Comment: In the /public directory

Comment: I am using Strapi-Beta, is that code working on beta version?

Comment: Hi, @Christin, I really appreciate for your reply, but can you explain more detail? That code doesn't working well on my side. I know you are right. but I want some more details. Can you help me once more?

Comment: Is working in 3.0.0.beta.19.5, i have a site running on it, i think this is out of scope of the questions asked. And will need more clarification or another question about the specific problem. Remember Strapi has a Slack for help.

Comment: Thanks, Great, It works well, I really appreciate to you. Thanks again.